# RVM Crash while running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm

I am using rvm 2.1.0 and Mac OS 10.9 and rails 4.1. My application fail when running rails sever. It show such bug

```
        /Users/amritdeepdhungana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
        ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

        -- Crash Report log information -----------------------------------

    ---------
       See Crash Report log file under the 
one of following:
         * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
         * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
         * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
         * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
       for more details.

    -- Control frame information ------------------------------------------
```

I search for the solution and try upgrade latest RVM i.e

```
$ rvm get head
$ rvm reload
$ rvm repair all
$ rvm use 2.1.0
```

But still it is getting same error.

Comment: When you write rvm use 2.1.0p0 you are actually using ruby 2.1.0p0. A segmentation fault means that there is a problem compiling your ruby code. Do you need the eventmachine gem in your app? If not, get rid of it and try running. Otherwise I use event machine with ruby 2.0.0, try downgrading to that version by doing `rvm use 2.0.0` and then do a `bundle install` just in case there are new dependencies to install and then run your rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 2.1.0 has [known issues](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/59728) which also involve segfaults.

Upgrade to 2.1.1: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/